# IndentationError: expected an indented block MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to import a json file into MangoDB, but get the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-2-64b0e1ec4bba>", line 13
    data = json.load(f)
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

And my code is:

```
import json, pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

cluster = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://Rokaya:140296@cluster0.mc9wz.mongodb.net/Hotel_Test?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
db = cluster['Hotel_Test']
collection = db['Hotel_Reviews_Test']

with open('/Users/rokayadarai/Desktop/Coding/DataSets/Hotel_Reviews.json') as f:
data = json.load(f)
collection.insert_many(data)
cluster.close()
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I not see something?

Comment: As the message says:`IndentationError: expected an indented block`, the block starting with this line has to be indented...

Comment: The last 3 lines of your code are subordinate to the `with` statement. That is called a block. The block needs to be indented to match the subordination, because indentation is significant in Python.

Comment: you should try to use a good ide like pycharm, vscode etc. These indentations are generally by default handled by the ide itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('/Users/rokayadarai/Desktop/Coding/DataSets/Hotel_Reviews.json') as f:
   data = json.load(f)
   collection.insert_many(data)
   cluster.close()
```

You need to indent the code as above, because you've used "with" python expects an indentation so it knows what to do with the .json file you've opened.